# Кто сможет перевести этот код с Pascal на Java прошу помочь

Tags: java, pascal

```
Writeln('Введите строку S ');
readln(S);
for i:=1 to length(S) do
begin
  if S[i]='а' then 
  begin
    if (i mod 2)=0 then 
      S[i]:='с' 
    else
      S[i]:='у'; 
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Расскажите что именно у вас вызывает затруднение? Как цикл написать или как `if` использовать? Или как ввод с консоли считать?

Comment: Вы бы сами попробовали, сказали, что не получается. А мы бы уже подсказали вам, как исправить

Comment: Я просто незнаю как это в java написать если можете напишите как

Comment: Читайте учебник Java.

Comment: Например, мне было бы нетрудно, но программист должен сам писать, чтобы научиться, или не надо этим заниматься.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String b = in.nextLine();
        StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer(b);

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == 'a') {
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    s.setCharAt(i, 'c');
                } else {
                    s.setCharAt(i, 'y');
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы молодцы, но на такие глупые вопросы лучше не отвечать.